# NetServerEnum returns 58, can't find this error code in the documentation

Tags: winapi, error-code

NetServerEnum returns error code 58, can't find this error code in the documentation.

What does it means?

Comment: Start a command prompt and just use `net helpmsg 58` to find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General Win32 error code 58 means:

58 The specified server cannot perform the requested operation. ERROR_BAD_NET_RESP

Are you trying the 100 or 101 level?

MSDN error page [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: thanks.
its 101 level.
I still dont understand what this error means and what can I do to make it work.

Comment: I was wondering if it was a security issue, as you are asking network servers to divulge more information than the basic 100 level query. Can you try querying level 100 instead (using the server_info_100 structure) ?

Comment: Hmmm. Running out of ideas. The last one is whether you have some form of firewall running on your machine which prevents your program from using the network?